# Why is Typesafe activator command `activator dependencies` not working?

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

I created a new project using Typesafe Activator. In the command prompt I execute the command `activator dependencies`. This results in:

```
E:\sample_app>activator dependencies
[info] Loading project definition from E:\sample_app\project
[info] Updating {file:/E:/sample_app/project/}sample_app-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to sample_app (in build file:/E:/sample_app/)
[error] Not a valid command: dependencies
[error] Not a valid project ID: dependencies
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: dependencies (similar: all-dependencies, rpm-dependencies, allDependencies)
[error] dependencies
[error]             ^
```

***Versions used***:

- Java version is 1.8.0_51,
- Activator is 1.3.6,
- OS is windows 8,
- 64 - bit OS.

Comment: Please reformulate your question, as it is not understandable. Also provide examples, so that one can reproduce your error!

Comment: Now you understood ( Martin Senne) this kind of error please give me a one good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Analysis

First, `dependencies` is not valid `sbt` commands. (All `sbt` commands can be used also in `activator`.)

### Solution

Either you mean `libraryDependencies` (which is an sbt setting) so call

```
activator libraryDependencies
```

Or you want to see the classpath of the dependencies ( a sbt task, so you need to use `show` to see the output of the sbt task), e.g.

```
activator "show dependencyClasspath"
```

#### Edit as of 2015-09-30,3:50am

If calling from console, the combined command must be put into quotes. Here: `"show dependencyClasspath"`

Comment: I try it but it throw given below error----->
E:\sample_app>activator show dependencyClasspath
[info] Loading project definition from E:\sample_app\project
[info] Set current project to sample_app (in build file:/E:/sample_app/)
[error] Not a valid command: show (similar: shell)
[error] Expected whitespace character
[error] Not a valid project ID: show
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: show (similar: showTiming, showSuccess, show-timing)
[error] show
[error]     ^

Comment: See my edit: You need to call `activator "show dependencyClasspath"` (I forgot to put it in quotes)

Comment: Sir That "activator show dependencyClasspath"  Throw this kind of error


E:\sample_app>activator show dependencyClasspath
[info] Loading project definition from E:\sample_app\project
[info] Set current project to sample_app (in build file:/E:/sample_app/)
[error] Not a valid command: show (similar: shell)
[error] Expected whitespace character
[error] Not a valid project ID: show
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: show (similar: showTiming, showSuccess, show-timing)
[error] show
[error]     ^

Comment: 1. Looks like you have not used the quotes "" as suggested? 2. What happens if you start activator with `activator` and then execute `show dependencyClasspath` in activator shell? 3. libraryDependencies is working, but not what you need?